"It wasn't until that moment that we understood it" — idiomatic. "It was until that moment that we didn't understand it" — not idiomatic. Why?
cambridge.org:

(1) Until the bill came yesterday, we didn’t realise what an expensive hotel it was.
(1a) It wasn’t until the bill came yesterday that we realised what an expensive hotel it was.

As far as I understand, (1a) is a cleft construction made from (1): to emphasize "until the bill came yesterday", it was put in front of the that-clause.
But why not make it the following way?:
(1b) It was until the bill came yesterday that we didn't realise what an expensive hotel it was.

I simplified the sentences:
(2) Until that moment we didn't understand it.
(2a) It wasn't until that moment that we understood it.
(2b) It was until that moment that we didn't understand it.
I was told here (2b) is not idiomatic English. Therefore, I infer that (1b) is not idiomatic too.
Why are (1b) and (2b) not idiomatic, whereas (1a) and (2a) are?

You're quite right that 1b / 2b aren't idiomatically valid. The "valid" versions with negation attached to until rather than to realise / understand are 1c: Not until the bill came yesterday did we realise what an expensive hotel it was, and 2c: Not until that moment did we understand it. Why? Because that's just how English works.

This is not really about English. Would 1b and 2b also not be the same in your language? In other words: they wouldn't make logical sense.

@FumbleFingers Did I understand you correctly?: i) From "Not until that moment did we understand it", we can make the following cleft construction: "It wasn't until that moment that we understood it" — idiomatic. ii) But from "Until that moment we didn't understand it", we cannot make the analogous cleft construction: "It was until that moment that we didn't understand it" — not idiomatic. iii) There is no logical explanation why it's so.

If you want too say that until some moment, you didn't understand it, which means you then understood it, fine, and that applies to your cleft one as well, but this is not about English.

Your simplifications are specious.
The structure

It was not until that moment that .....

expresses a sudden change of circumstance.
Negating the assertion in the content-clause is hardly the inverse of a sudden change of circumstance.

Until that moment, ...

A long-standing circumstance is not the inverse of a sudden change of circumstance.
So I suppose the underlying question is "How does It was not until that moment express the notion of a sudden change of circumstance vis-a-vis the assertion in the content clause?"
"It was not" negates the assertion in the content-clause.

It was not until that moment that I really knew what snow was.

=> It was that I did not really know what snow was until that moment.
or more idiomatic:
=> It was that I had not really known what snow was until that moment.
This would be unidiomatic:

It was that I had really known what snow was not until that moment.

and this would be unidiomatic:

It was that I had really known not until that moment what snow was.

in both instances because the negation is on the wrong (or at least the suboptimal) constituent.

For some unknown reason, native English speakers perceive (2a) and (2b) not as a cleft construction (where the PP "until that moment" and the that-clause are different constituents), but as ordinary sentences (where "until that moment + that-clause" is just a long PP). To me as a learner, such an approach seems very odd.

If, in a cleft construction, a that-clause has negation, does it always sound unnatural to you?

For instance, I found an example containing the following explanation: (5) It was not my dog that ate the apple. – natural; (6) It was my dog that didn't eat the apple. – odd in most cases but can be natural for example in the situation where a number of dogs are presented with different foods (including an apple) as part of some research. All the dogs ate the apple apart from one, and the researcher, seeing one apple left untouched, then asks "Whose dog didn't eat the apple?". Is (6) natural to you in terms of the context suggested? Thanks.

@Loviii,  Yes. Two special circumstances are necessary for it to be idiomatic: 1)  the negated fact is a distinguishing feature and 2)  the speaker is referring to the negated fact to clarify something for the listener.  Person A: My son told me that every  kid but one wanted to go to the zoo for the  class field trip. Do you know who that one kid was?  Person B: It was my daughter who didn't want to go to the zoo. She wanted to go to the art museum.
